# How can we get regression coefficients from a Keras linear regression model?

Tags: python, keras, linear-regression, tf.keras

A multiple linear regression model with k predictors X1, X2, ..., Xk
and a response Y , can be written as y = β0 + β1X1 + β2X2 + ··· βkXk + ".

I followed the tutorial here to use tf.keras to do basic regression. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression. Is it possible to output the β variables so I can examine how they contribute to the response?

The model the tutorial has you build looks like this by the way:

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model
```

Where `len(train_dataset.keys())` is 9.

Comment: I may be understanding the use case for Keras improperly. Perhaps it's better to use sklearn for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weights are stored in:

```
model.layers[n].weights
```

with `layers` a list and `n` the layer index in the model.

In your example, because input shape is `(9,)`

```
>>> len(model.layers[0].weights)
2
>>> model.layers[0].weights[0].shape
TensorShape([9, 64])
>>> model.layers[0].weights[1].shape
TensorShape([64])
```

To interpret these, imagine the first layer is to compute `h = ReLU(Ax+b)` with `x` a vector of `(9,)` then `A` is a matrix of shape `(9,64)` and `b` a vector of shape `(64,)`, and `h` also a vector of shape `(64,)`. Therefore, `model.layers[0].weights` is the list `[A, b]` of two weight tensors.

It is **not** linear regression. If you want it to be, you need to make a simpler model:

```
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())])
  ])

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

  model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
  return model
```

Then, after training with data, `model.layers[0].weights[0]` will have shape `(9,1)`, which are your  β1, β2, ..., βk; and `model.layers[0].weights[1]` will have shape `(1,)`, which is your β0

Comment: In this case for layer 0 or 1 the output would be an array of 64 weights. How do I interpret those 64 weights into the 10 regression coefficients? Is there some calculation to do?

Comment: @teddy I expanded the answer

Comment: The math checks out when I pass in `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`!